# Material UI checkbox toggle value based off input from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I have an unchecked checkbox. I am trying to change the value of it based off of data from an object. The object is from an SQL select boolean column 'T' or 'F'. If the value is 'T' then the box would be checked vise versa. I tried using a useState() that viewed the value but that didn't work.

```
  const [checkBoxState, setCheckBoxState] = React.useState(false);
  //check to see if values are 't' or 'f' to change them to vaiable formats
  function handleCheckState(databaseCondition) {
    if (databaseCondition == "T") {
      setCheckBoxState = true;
    }
    console.log(checkBoxState);
    return checkBoxState;
  }
```

This is the useState() I tried using.

```
<Checkbox checked={handleCheckState(data["validcycle"])} />
```

Here is the checkbox I want to toggle on/off based off that sql column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend, you forgot to enclose hook in brackets, example : setState(value)

```
    const [checkBoxState, setCheckBoxState] = React.useState(false)

    function handleCheckState(databaseCondition) {
        if (databaseCondition == 'T') setCheckBoxState(true)
        else setCheckBoxState(false)
        return checkBoxState
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change the state using:

```js
setCheckBoxState(true);
```

instead of:

```js
setCheckBoxState = true;
```

---

the better approach is simply like this:

```js
<Checkbox checked={databaseCondition === "T"} />
```

Comment: how am I supposed to implement '<Checkbox checked={databaseCondition === "T"} />'? Do I still need to call the function but just return databaseCondition instead?

Comment: @Zachphilipp No, there is no need to call the function in this approach,, "checked" will be true if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: data['validcycle'] is the reference to the value that equals 'T' yet when I do data['validcycle'] === 'T', it still remains unchecked. Can the state of a checkbox not change once it is set? I pull the object when I click another button in the program so the value of data['validcycle'] is initially null because it has not yet been filled with the new data I have when I pull it

Comment: @Zachphilipp I think `data?.validcycle` will resolve your issue.

Comment: nope, it still remains unchecked even though that value does equal 'T'